# SUBSTR in laravel query builder returns an error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a query here using a querybuilder and eloquent with the mysql function `substr` and my problem is it returns an error of `A non-numeric value encountered`. Can someone know what is the solution of this? Thanks.

My data is `1-Course 101` and i want to get only the `Course 101` ignoring the `1-` part in the database.

The queries I tried

My eloquent query

```
 $items2 = Course::where('school_id','=',Auth::user()->school_id)
      ->where(\DB::raw('SUBSTR(name, LOCATE('-', name) +  1)'))
      ->where('status','=',1) 
      ->get();
```

Query builder

```
 $items3 = \DB::table('courses')
                  ->where('status', '=', 1)
                  ->where('school_id','=',Auth::user()->school_id)
                  ->where(\DB::raw('SUBSTR(name, LOCATE('-', name) +  1)'))
                  ->get();
```

It still returns an error `A non-numeric value encountered`.

Comment: why are you adding it in `where`. it should come in `select`

Comment: what do you mean it should come in `select` sir?

Comment: you want to get the data right? but you add it in `where` without any condition.

Comment: So do you mean i should write the query like this `$items2 = Course::select('SUBSTR(name, LOCATE('-', name) +  1)')` ?

Comment: please try my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$items2 = Course::select(\DB::raw("SUBSTR(name, LOCATE('-', name) +  1) as name"))
       ->where('school_id','=',Auth::user()->school_id)
       ->where('status','=',1) 
       ->get();
```

use select to get the specific column and don't forget to alias the column as name just to be sure. The query you were using fetch all the data from the database.

Comment: You are completely changing the meaning of query if you move something from WHERE part to SELECT part.

Comment: He wants Course 101 ignoring the 1- part .

Comment: @VincentDaveTe you might be right, but you shouldn't post just code without any explanation if you are chaning the meaning of query like that.

Comment: So far, this answer is the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

the problem is string concatenation.
in the question, the `DB:raw` was

```
\DB::raw('SUBSTR(name, LOCATE('-', name) +  1)')
```

the `'-'` breaks the string. that was the issue.

```
 $items2 = Course::select(\DB::raw("SUBSTR(name, LOCATE('-', name) +  1)"))
           ->where('school_id','=',Auth::user()->school_id)
           ->where('status','=',1) 
           ->get();
```

or

```
$items2 = Course::selectRaw("SUBSTR(name, LOCATE('-', name) +  1)")
               ->where('school_id','=',Auth::user()->school_id)
               ->where('status','=',1) 
               ->get();
```

Comment: It gets me an error sir `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Comment: made some changes. please try now. I am updating from my mobile phone.

Comment: same error encountered `A non-numeric value encountered`

Comment: ok sir. please return the query and comment your query. instead of `->get()` use `->toSql()` . and `print_r($items2)`

Comment: we can Identify the issue from query generated

Comment: no query generated sir it just returns an error `A non-numeric value encountered`

Comment: fine. please remove `->where('school_id','=',Auth::user()->school_id)` and try.

Comment: made one more edit in my answer. please try that tooo.

Comment: ok i tried it already and it works! unfortunately i cant get the value from my option tag. But its ok. Thanks for the help

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran You should add the explanation to the answer because someone else might find this question in future.

Answer (score 1):

does not contain a numeric value ?

Should change \DB::raw('SUBSTR(name, LOCATE('-', name) ***+  1***);

Comment: \DB::raw('SUBSTR(name, LOCATE('-', name) +  1)') must change
\DB::raw('SUBSTR(name, LOCATE('-', name)'), '+', 1')

Answer (score 1):

Why not use map to format the name:

Hope I get your point using this code.

```
Course::where('school_id','=',Auth::user()->school_id)
    ->where('status','=',1) 
    ->get()->map(function ($data) {
        $name = explode("-", $data->name); // 1-Course 101 - ['1', 'Course 101']
        return [
          'name' => $name[1]
        ];
  })
```

Comment: Read some documentation about laravel collection.